# HTML Canvas Translate + Rotate problems?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, rotation, translation

I wrote a function that draws and rotates a rectangle in place:

```
  let centerX = myCanvas.width / 2;
  let centerY = myCanvas.height / 2;


  function drawRectangle() {
     angle += 10;

     theContext.save();

     theContext.lineWidth = 2;
     theContext.translate(centerX, centerY);

     theContext.rotate(angle * (Math.PI / 180));

     theContext.strokeStyle = "blue";

     theContext.strokeRect(0, 0, squareSize, -squareSize);
     theContext.restore();
  }
        

  let looper = setInterval(drawRectangle, 40);
```

It works great! Here's the output:

[image]

As you can see I'm animating the Square counter-clockwise.

I made its registration point be it's lower left corner, and I have it starting at the precise middle of the Canvas.

Here's what it looks like when it's almost completed it's full 360 degree cycle:

[image]

I'm now trying to do the same thing with a Hexagon - but I'm getting wildly different results.

As you can see the first Hex is drawn in the middle of the screen (sorta, the registration point isn't exactly what I wanted it to be, but it'll do) - but the rest of the Hexagons go way off:

[image]

Here's how it looks when it's close to its 360 degree cycle:

[image]

Obviously there's something wrong with the values I'm passing into my `translate` statement (`theContext.translate(lastX, lastY)`) - and believe me, I've tried passing ***all sorts*** of values into `translate` that I thought made sense.

I just want that Hexagon to remain exactly where it is, in the center of the screen, and simply rotate about its registration point - which should be the center of the screen, either clockwise or counter-clock wise. (Ultimately, I'd like to do this with any Polygon - from simple Triangles to Pentagons to Dodecagons and more, but one thing at a time.)

Any ideas what I need to do to get this going properly?

Here's my Hexagon code:

```
  let hexCenterX = myCanvas.width / 2 - hexSize;
  let hexCenterY = myCanvas.height / 2;
  let hexSize = 60;

  function drawHexagon() {
     theContext.save();

     theContext.translate(hexCenterX, hexCenterY);
     if(isRotating) {
        theContext.rotate(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
     }

     theContext.beginPath();
     theContext.moveTo(hexCenterX + hexSize * Math.cos(0), hexCenterY + hexSize * Math.sin(0));

     for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        console.log(" >Math.cos(i) = ", Math.cos(i));
        theContext.lineTo(hexCenterX + hexSize * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6), hexCenterY + hexSize * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
     }

     theContext.closePath();
     theContext.strokeStyle = "blue";
     theContext.stroke();

     theContext.restore();
     incrementAngle();
  }
```

Comment: Your shape origin needs to be zero like your rect's origin.

Comment: No I tried that and it didn't help at all.

Comment: OK this works - but it's very different from the way I was trying to - and NEED to do it, which was to very purposefully use `setInterval()`.  Cause I need to *show* the polygons being drawn - not have them all be there, already fully drawn when the user loads the page, and also I need to control the *speed* at which they're drawn. Also, in your fiddle code you're importing this min'd file called "path2D-inspection.min.js" - what is that? And do I *have* to use that? And what if I'm not permitted to use that? (There are other issues as well - and I don't mean to sound ungrateful here! ThankU!)

Comment: No you don't need the extra JS that was just for me to check your hex actual height. And you can very well use a setInterval instead of the sync loop I used. I only filled the gap of what you didn't show. Here it's cleaned out of my path stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/am0puqge/

Comment: OK - I made my changes and everything works well now. THANK YOU!  However, I can't credit you with the right answer because you didn't submit your advice as an "answer", only as a "comment"! Please submit it the "right way" so I can credit you properly!